# Getting an error when calculating F1 score and other metrics in Python

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have made a Python project that uses deep learning using PyTorch. I am getting the following error message when calculating the F1 score:

```
'Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass-multioutput
and multilabel-indicator targets'
```

My code:

```
model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(135, 50),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(50, 50),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(50, max_length),
    nn.Sigmoid()
)

epochs = 1000
loss_fn = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)
model.train()
for epoch in range(epochs):
  for X_train, y_train in Dataloader:
    y_pred = model(X_train)
    # Convert the target tensor to torch.float32 data type
    y_train = y_train.float()
    loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y_train)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    print(loss.item())
    optimizer.step()

model.eval()
y_pred = model(X_test)
y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5).float()  # Threshold the probabilities to get binary predictions
acc = (y_pred == y_test).float().mean()
print("Model accuracy: %.2f%%" % (acc*100))
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you compute those metrics all-in-one. They should be per-class computed.